# MySQL connection prompts for password even though this is in the connection string

Tags: mysql, delphi, odbc

This one looks like a bizarre one.

I have a Pascal unit that connects to a MySQL database

```
unit u_MySQLConnection;

interface

uses
  ADODB,
  AnsiStrings,
  Generics.Collections,
  SysUtils,
  DB
  ;

type
  TMySQLConnection = class
    strict private
      mysqlCon : TADOConnection;
    public
      function Connect:boolean;
      destructor Destroy;
  end;

var
  MySQLConnection : TMySQLConnection;

implementation

function TMySQLConnection.Connect:boolean;
var
    success : boolean;
begin

    success := true;
    try

      if NOT (mysqlCon = nil)
      then mysqlCon.Destroy;

      mysqlCon := TADOConnection.Create(nil);

      mysqlCon.ConnectionString := 'DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; SERVER=localhost; DATABASE=database; UID=root; PASSWORD=password;OPTION=3;';

    except
        success := false;
    end;

    Result := success;
end;

destructor TMySQLConnection.Destroy;
begin
    FreeAndNil(mysqlCon);
    inherited;
end;

end.
```

And when I try to connect

```
MySQLConnection := TMySQLConnection.Create;

try
    MySQLConnection.Connect;
finally
    MySQLConnection.Destroy;
end;
```

I get a password prompt dialog box appearing, even though the password is already in the connection string. If I enter the username and password into this prompt, everything else works fine.

Things get a little bit more strange here:

When i move the database connection command into the main .dpr file as shown

```
program DieselBatch;

uses
  Vcl.Forms,
  u_MySQLConnection in '..\src\u_MySQLConnection.pas'
  (*,
  frm_About in '..\src\frm_About.pas' {frmAbout},
  frm_AnalystDetails in '..\src\frm_AnalystDetails.pas' {frmAnalystDetails},
  frm_Batch in '..\src\frm_Batch.pas' {frmBatch},
  frm_ConfirmResultsChanged in '..\src\frm_ConfirmResultsChanged.pas' {frmConfirmResultsChanged},
  frm_DebugSample in '..\src\frm_DebugSample.pas' {frmDebugSample},
  frm_FlashManualEntry in '..\src\frm_FlashManualEntry.pas' {frmFlashEntry},
  frm_Main in '..\src\frm_Main.pas' {frmMain},
  frm_SampleComment in '..\src\frm_SampleComment.pas' {frmSampleComment},
  frm_SelectAnalystForResult in '..\src\frm_SelectAnalystForResult.pas' {frmSelectAnalystForResult},
  u_Data in '..\src\u_Data.pas',
  u_MicroCheck in '..\src\u_MicroCheck.pas',
  u_Undo in '..\src\u_Undo.pas'
  *)
  ;

{$R *.res}

var
  MySQLConnection : TMySQLConnection;

begin

  MySQLConnection := TMySQLConnection.Create;

  try
      MySQLConnection.Connect;
  finally
      MySQLConnection.Destroy;
  end;
```

Then the password prompt does not appear, as long as those units are commented out.

When I uncomment the above units again, the problem reappears.

Some of those units do use ADODB and DB but I can't see how the mere presence of the units should affect the behavour of the MySQLConnection unit ....

Comment: Tried setting `LoginPrompt` of 'mysqlCon' to false?

Comment: After this: mysqlCon := TADOConnection.Create(nil); add mysqlcon.LoginPromt := false;

Comment: The ODBC attribute for the password is PWD not PASSWORD although the mysql driver might understand password too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Short answer

Set the `LoginPrompt` property of the connection object to `False`.

## Why it does not appear when you comment all the form units?

Well, the common DoConnect method of the TCustomConnection descendants checks the `LoginPrompt` property and then calls the `LoginDialogProc`/`LoginDialogExProc` procedural variable if assigned. The variables are declared in `Data.DB.pas`.

The VCL itself assigns this variables in the `initialization` section of the `VCL.DBLogDlg.pas` unit, which contains the standard dialog box you see, and this unit is used by the `DBCtrls.pas` unit, and automatically added to your project when you use any data-aware control.

If you comment out all the units containing data aware controls, the `DBCtrls.pas` unit is not linked in your executable and, as a consequence there's no *registered* login dialog to show when you're connecting.

Comment: +1 Especially for the explanation of why the prompt doesn't appear without any forms present/active in the app.